# Youtubeplayer in a fragment into a viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

i'm trying to load a `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment` in a `fragment` into a `viewpager`, but i cant load 2 or more `YouTubePlayerSupportFragment`.

If i load 2 or more i get the next error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
```

But if load 1 it work correctly.

How can i load?

Thanks for all and sorry for my bad english.

The xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="20dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTituloTecnica"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#045FB4" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:background="#08088A" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivTecnica"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView -->
        <!-- android:id="@+id/youtube_view" -->
        <!-- android:layout_width="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_height="match_parent" -->
        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="15dp" /> -->

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And the code that load the view:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// if (view == null) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tecnica_list_item, container, false);
// }

Bundle b = this.getArguments();
tecnica = ViewPagerAdapter.tecnicas.get(b.getInt("tecnica"));

TextView titulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTituloTecnica);
titulo.setText(tecnica.getNombre());

TextView descripcion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvDescripcion);
descripcion.setText(tecnica.getDescripcion());

ImageView imagenTecnica = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivTecnica);
imagenTecnica.setImageResource(this
        .getActivity()
        .getResources()
        .getIdentifier("drawable/" + tecnica.getRutaImagen(), null,
                this.getActivity().getPackageName()));



this.videoId = tecnica.getUrlYoutube();

PlayerYouTubeFrag myFragment = PlayerYouTubeFrag.newInstance(videoId);

this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, myFragment).commit();
myFragment.init();

return view;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to attach a newly cleated fragment to a fragment, not a container.
I guess you are trying to use the currently instantiated fragment in the layout and this layout is a ViewPager detail page frament, right?.

You can't use nested fragments declaring them on the layout xml. You must put a placeholder layout on the first fragment xml and inject it on code.

Some thing like:

```
...

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvDescripcion"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/youtube_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
...
```

and on the ViewPager detail fragment:

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = YouTubePlayerSupportFragment.newInstance();
getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.youtube_fragment, youTubePlayerFragment).commit();

...
```

Do not forget to initializar properly the player with

```
 youTubePlayerFragment.initialize(apiKey, new OnInitializedListener() {

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
            // Play, cue or whatever you want to do with the player
    }


    ... // Implement other inteface methods here

    });
```

Comment: Hi!Thank you very much for your answer, and sorry for the delay.

It works pretty well, but when I change views quickly, youtube breaks.
How can i resolve it?